# Creating XML on IBM DB2 Mainframe

Tags: xml, attributes, db2

So far this is what I have:

```
SELECT
XMLSERIALIZE(
  XMLDOCUMENT(
    XMLELEMENT(NAME "cfdi:Comprobante",  
      XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3',
                    'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS "xsi",
                    'http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3' AS "cfdi"),
      XMLATTRIBUTES('[Field1]' AS "Field1")
    )
  ) AS CLOB(1M) INCLUDING XMLDECLARATION
)
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

The XML I am trying to copy has an attribute; "xsi:SchemaLocation" which contains several http paths, each separated by a space.  It also seems that "xsi:SchemaLocation" is a System reserved word, so there doesn't seem to be a straight forward way for me to set it.  The company receiving the XML file requires that the attribute be included in the document.  Does anyone have any idea how to get this attribute to appear in XML I am generating??

Answer (score 0):

You should add it in the XMLATTRIBUTES tag such as:

```
XMLATTRIBUTES("http://example1.com http://example2.com" AS "xsi:SchemaLocation")
```